# Detecting for/if/while statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm coding a .cpp parser in C#, and I need to detect `for/if/while` statements. At first I thought that trimming the lines and checking if current line starts with `for/if/while` would be enough. However I've been told that there may be some exceptions and that solution wouldn't work properly. Which exceptions are there that I should think of? Which characters can occur before a statement? Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write simple parser for if and while statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294238/how-to-write-simple-parser-for-if-and-while-statements)

Comment: Surely all of the answers to all of these kinds of questions would be in example cpp files?

Comment: e.g., ( var == 5) ? "yes" : "no"... and also are you seeking C++ or C# solution

Comment: @JoachimPileborg there may be no space before `for`. `if(1==1){}for(...){}` is perfectly valid

Comment: @NirMH seeking a C# solution

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it can always be a string body `"{if}"`

Comment: When you say ".cpp parser", do you actually mean a full blown parser, able to parse all valid C++ code (according to a version of some standard) or are you parsing C-like code which can be more constrained?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen A valid C++ code.

Comment: Then you need to write a full blown parser. You can't read this line by line, C++ code is much much much more complex than that. The topic of a full blown parser is too broad for a SO question. You will need to get a book on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Trimming the line won't work if it looks like this:

```
/* hello */ while(true) ;
```

or this:

```
/*
   while(true) ;
 */
```

You'll need to (at the least) pre-process the file (if it's C++)

Answer (score 1):

You may have several statements in one line, code like

```
f(1); while(x > 0)
{
}
```

though not elegant is perfectly valid. Generally C++ is too complicated language for such solutions as checking if line starts with something.

Answer (score 1):

you may encounter a function like this or may be a lambda function.

```
void max(a,b){if (a>b) return a; return b;}
```

You can use Regular expression for this

Answer (score 1):

The way compilers work is they run the source code through a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), which converts the source into Tokens or a Token graph.

You'll need to create one for C#.  The best place to start is probably by looking at the `gcc` compiler for linux: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Lexer.html#Lexer

Of if you want to just explore along, you could get a very rough tokenization by using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and passing in all expression terminators:

```
var expressionTerminators = new []{';','{','}'};

var sourceTokens = sourceCode.Split(expressionTerminators);

var forIfWhileStatements = sourceTokens.Where(
          x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("if") || 
               x.ToLower().StartsWith("for") || 
               x.ToLower().StartsWith("while"));
```

But again, this is a non-ideal approach.